# Racing condition when replacing transactions

Tags: transactions, pending-transactions, txpool, receipts, defi

I'm writing a bot that monitors a DeFi protocol for liquidation opportunities. The bot behaves like in the pseudo-code below:

```
let pending_txs: [];

for every_new_block in Ethereum {
  // Check the state of pending txs.
  for pending_tx in pending_txs {
    let receipt = get_receipt(pending_tx);

    if receipt != null {
      // If we got a receipt from Ethereum, clear the tx from the local state.
      delete_tx_from_array(pending_tx);
    } else {
      // Otherwise, replace the tx and update it in the array.
      let new_gas_price = bump_gas_price(pending_tx.gas_price);
      let tx = send_tx(new_gas_price);
      update_tx_in_array(tx);
    }
  }

  ...
   
  // Search for new liquidation opportunities.
  if liquidation_opportunity and if !pending_tx_for_liquidation_opportunity {
    let tx = send_tx(initial_gas_price);
    add_tx_in_array(tx);
  }
}
```

The above works well most of the times, but there it an exception:

1. Submit tx `0x123`
2. Wait 15 seconds, check if we got a receipt from Ethereum.
3. If we didn't, re-calculate the gas price and send a replacement tx `0xabc`.
4. By the time the replacement tx `0xabc` is broadcast to the Ethereum network, the `0x123` gets mined.
5. The bot will attempt to replace the `0xabc` tx forever, because the receipt is always `null` for `0xabc`.

When I update the tx in the array, I also override the previous tx hash (this makes the implementation simple). In other words, the script ceases to be aware of past tx hashes once it broadcasts a replacement tx, which causes an infinite regress when a racing condition occurs.

The question is whether there is any way to avoid this situation? I've only run my bot on Rinkeby, against an Infura node. Maybe it's something that happens frequently on testnets, but rarely on mainnet?

I know that one solution is to modify the code to track multiple tx hashes per liquidation opportunity, but that would greatly increase the complexity of the implementation (I'm using Rust).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the nonce and transaction count to validate if the nonce was mined.

```
if (tx.nonce < getTransactionCount(sender)) {
  drop transaction
}
```

I don't think this situation is particular to testnets. I'd say it is worse in mainnet where short chain reorgs are common.

Comment: Riiight, so I would add this in the `else` block. I forgot about the relation between the account nonce and the dropping of txs. Cheers!

Comment: **Update**: shouldn't it be `getTransactionCount(sender) > tx.nonce`? What I want is to stop replacing the tx if the tx count of the sender has increased. If the tx count is equal to the tx nonce, then I can safely replace the tx.

Comment: @PaulRazvanBerg You are correct. `getTransactionCount(sender)` is the next nonce to be mined so `tx.nonce < getTransactionCount(sender)` we are sure it was mined.